# Buzzing sound after 1.5 to 3 minutes playing audio or video

Tags: sound

I have Ubuntu 21.10 installed on ACER Aspire switch 10 laptop/tablet.
When I play audio or video using internal speakers for sound output, after 1.5-3 minutes I get buzzing sound from the speakers instead of played audio. Then I restart the application and it helps. This occurs for any application playing audio (vlc, mpv, firefox). But when I use Bluetooth audio as output everything works perfect.
What should I check and where to look?

**UPD:**

I tested the internal speakers with installer USB in 'Try Ubuntu' mode.

Ubuntu 21.10 installer USB (try mode) - starts buzzing

Ubuntu 20.04 installer USB (try mode) - NO buzzing (i.e. works fine)

So I think this is clearly a software issue.

Also I tested external HDMI audio (TV) as output - NO buzzing (i.e. works fine)

So how do I find and check the sound settings ?

Comment: This might be a hardware issue. Can you see if the problem occurs when using a live CD?

Comment: Live CD: with 21.10 it starts buzzing, with 20.04 it works perfectly (i.e. NO buzzing). Now it is clear that this is software issue. Thank you. Now the question is - is it wrong settings or bug in code. So how do I find and check the sound settings ?

Comment: it looks like you have these issues vanished using external ac/dc plugged devices or own power source, have you tried some static extraction? (did u dissamblee your device previously?)

Comment: The problem (buzzing) with internal speakers in 21.10 did NOT vanish. All the described tests I did with AC adapter plugged in. What do you mean by 'static extraction'? I do not remember right now if I ever disassembled the device... Maybe I replaced a battery some time ago, but not sure. But how is it connected to the buzzing problem?